# How to apply css flex concept to angular material

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox, angular-material

My css code for navigation drawer

```css
:host{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f0fff0;
    flex-grow:1;
}

.body-style{
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```html
 <mat-drawer-container >
    <mat-drawer #drawer [mode]="over">I'm a drawer</mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">Toggle drawer</button>
        <div class="body-style"> 
            <router-outlet>

            </router-outlet>
        </div>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

I am obviously missing something in Flexbox concepts. The `<mat-drawer-content>`'s width is small.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't reinvent the wheel**.

Angular team has already covered your need with [**Flex-Layout**](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

Once installed, it gives this :

```html
<mat-drawer-container >
  <mat-drawer #drawer [mode]="over">I'm a drawer</mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">Toggle drawer</button>
    <div class="body-style"> 
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

No CSS required.

Comment: tried with same approach, facing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581755/flex-layout-used-in-mat-drawer-content)

Comment: That's another question, is this one resolved ? If so, please mark it as resolved (either with my answer or your own). I'm going on your link to see what your issue is.