# Flex layout used in mat-drawer-content

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have used angular flex layout in navigation drawer like this

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" >
      <p>Drawer content</p>
      <p>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.close()">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </p>
      </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">

      <p>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.open()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </p>

   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

but it looks like [image]

how to stretch mat-drawer-container upto footer?

Comment: also add the html for your header and footer

Comment: `<header fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end ">
  <div  fxLayout="row" >
    <fw-menu>
    </fw-menu>
  </div>
  <div  fxLayout="row" >
    <fw-top-bar>
    </fw-top-bar>
  </div>
</header>`  and then footer `<footer fxLayout="row">
    I am a sticky footer
  </footer>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that your items aren't stretched.

Start by giving your html and body tags a full height :

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Next, you have to make a main container, where you will put your header, container, and footer. This main container will be stretched and flexed.

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="column">
  <header fxFlex="10%"/>
  <drawer fxFlex/>
  <footer fxFlex="10%"/>
</div>
```

In this setup, your header and footer will take 10% of the page each, and the drawer will take the remaining space.

Comment: here is a [link](https://angular-pd6umw.stackblitz.io/) that i have tried. still the container is not expanded. [edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pd6umw?) link

Comment: If you don't give all your elements an height, they won't take the full height. You have to explicitly state that they have a full height, either by `height: 100%` or by adding the `fxFlex` attribute. [Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emc4zp?file=src%2Fframework%2Fcontent%2Fcontent.component.html)

Comment: there is scroll bar. since there is no content, which element causes this? is there is any way without giving css. only flex layout. And i want a button on headers left side, to show/hide the drawer. which approach should i use to communicate between components?

Comment: That's because you gave wrong height properties to your elements. I've corrected your issue about fitting the page, that's another issue you have there and I really don't want to fiddle in your code to find it. Just to help you, know that `height: 100%` means 100% of the parent height, not 100% of the remaining height. That's probably what happens here, as the scrolls is the size of the footer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

<mat-sidenav-container class="menu-container">
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'fullscreen' to stretch it to footer.

```
<mat-drawer-container fullscreen>
   <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" >
    <p>Drawer content</p>
    <p>
      <button mat-icon-button>
       <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </p>
  </mat-drawer>
<mat-drawer-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">

  <p>
    <button mat-icon-button>
     <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
   </button>
 </p>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: Plus, this attribute doesn't exist, neither in HTML nor in Angular Material.